# "Predication" — the logicians' usage

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, is-it-a-word

> There are several distinct ways to differentiate men and women — chromosomal analysis, self identification, and visual inspection — we review each **predication** below…

Here **predication** is referring to one of: chromosomal analysis, self identification or visual inspection. The idea is that chromosomal analysis provides a predicate ("men have XY; women have XX") which is used to distinguish the sexes.

Am I using the word correctly here?

Other options might include:

- Distinguisher — I made that up
- Distinguishment — also made up
- Differentiator — I'd like to use word variety if possible and not reuse this word in the sentence
- Discriminator — perhaps only engineers use this word, also unfortunately "discriminate" has negative baggage which is not wanted here
- Standard — this is unnecessarily generic, a discriminator is more specific than a standard

---

In engineering and programming contexts it is common that you need to choose a word to describe each of a group of things. And then you use that word to represent those things. This is context in which I'm asking. -- For example "pick a number between 1 and 10 and then multiply *that number* by five". And programmers will say `$pickedNumber * 5`. -- This is why I'm seeking a specific word choice rather than a way to reword the sentence to avoid choosing this word.

Comment: *Predication* here just means a claim of fact. There are three such claims about sexual differentiation and the author (you?) will review each of them.

Comment: Have you considered simply omitting the word? That is, "... we review each of these below", or even "we review each below". Keep it simple :)

Comment: In engineering and programming contexts it is common that you need to choose a word to describe each of a group of things. And then you use that word to represent those things. This is context in which I'm asking. -- For example "pick a number between 1 and 10 and then multiply *that number* by five". And programmers will say `$pickedNumber + 5`. -- This is why I'm seeking a specific word choice rather than a way to reword the sentence to avoid choosing this word.

Comment: Am I triggering people because this example mentions gender, a sensitive topic, or is word choice off-topic for this Stack Exchange community?

Comment: The last paragraph of the question, added later, makes the question less, rather than more, clear. In every conceptual framework there are broad concepts covering several of the narrower ones; that is not in any way specific to engineering and programming.

Comment: Of course, good programmers will translate *multiply that number by five* into `$pickedNumber * 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word that is needed here seems to be *criterion*. It is better than *predication*, because any quality that something happens to possess can be called its predicate; using *criterion* makes it clear that one is speaking of a quality that is used as a basis for classification.